# How to refresh resolve?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using `ui-router`, I have a state with a resolve function:

```
.state('tab.social', {
    url: '/social/',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/social/tab-social.html',
        controller: 'SocialCtrl',
        resolve: {
          socialAuthResolve: socialAuthResolve
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

I capture the resolve in the controller as follows:

```
.controller('SocialCtrl', function($scope, SocialAuth, socialAuthResolve) {
    //
    console.log(socialAuthResolve);

    //
    $scope.logOut = function() {
       SocialAuth.logOut();
       $state.go('tab.social', {}, {reload: true});
    };

    //
    $scope.logIn= function() {
       SocialAuth.logIn();
       $state.go('tab.social', {}, {reload: true});
    };
})
```

However, when either pressing `logOut` or `logIn`, my state is not refreshed. I am using some parameters from the resolve `socialAuthResolve` and would like this to be updated. In this case, the old parameters are still in there.

Only when I refresh my browser, then the variables and the page are updated accordingly. How can I refresh the page after the `logOut` and `logIn`? For instance, force to resolve again?

Comment: "resolve" sounds like a promise, and promises can only be resolved once.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample state with config:

```
.state('app.stateName', {
      url: "/theUrl",
      views: {
        'myViewName': {
          templateUrl: "templates/template.html",
          controller: 'SomeController',
          resolve: {
            pleaseResolve: function() {
              console.log("I am resolved");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

In my controller (assuming `SomeController` as mentioned above), whenever I enter into the state I run this.

```
var res = ($state.$current.self.views.myViewName.resolve.pleaseReslove)
res.call()
```

This will call my resolve function every time I come into the view.